# How can I create a player that continues playing on all pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, frame

The thing that I want to know is how to create a frame around the site that stays constant and at the same time and **change the url in the address bar depending on the actual page being shown**. It needs to be able to have an audio element that plays **nonstop** even if you go to another page on the server.

[Pitchfork Website](http://www.pitchfork.com/), the player can be seen in the upper righthand corner.

Comment: not super familiar with pitchpork, can you do it in a master page?

Comment: That site isn't going to different pages on the server, it's just using JavaScript's history api to make it look like you're at a different URL while using AJAX to replace the content of the webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swapping out content and then updating the URL sounds like a pattern that Mark Pilgrim goes over in http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

With a little AJAX you can update your content, `history.pushState()` allows you to change the URL, and then add an event listener to listen to the `popstate` event (when the user navigates backwards).

*This doesn't really give much guidance as to how you should structure your page or AJAX calls but hopefully it gives you an idea of the general concept.*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you can include your resource as a template to your site (include it in every page, while taking into account the width and length of your main frame and the resource's size).